# Allow PHP to execute in a specific subdirectory, when parent directory is denied?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, php, htaccess

I operate a small shared server and would like to give some of my users the ability to execute PHP code from the browser (but not all of them) but have been unable to do so.

In the top level directory I have the directive in a .htaccess file:

> AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi
>
> Options -ExecCGI

to not allow script execution.

In the lower-level folders I have tried to add a .htaccess file with the following directives:

> AddHandler cgi-script .php
>
> Options ExecCGI

However this didn't work. The PHP file is returned as text in the browser.

I am running Apache with CentOS. If anyone knows how to set this up would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> > AddHandler cgi-script .php
> >
> > Options ExecCGI
>
> However this didn't work. The PHP file is returned as text in the browser.

Just like you used `Options -ExecCGI` to revoke privileges, use the exact opposite, `Options +ExecCGI` to grant them

Comment: I've tried with +ExecCGI too, unfortunately scripts are still not rendered as php in that folder. Maybe I'm missing a directive?